# Showing some data in rows as columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server 2014 that returns a list of students that belong to more than one club. This data is retrieved from a relationship table listed below:

```
ID       Student      ClubName
==============================
1        Bob          Chess
2        Bob          Tennis
3        Frank        Soccer
4        Frank        Math
5        Tom          Chess
6        Tom          Math
7        Tom          Drama
```

I can list the number students that belong to more than one club using the following query.

```
SELECT Student, COUNT(ClubName)
FROM StudentClub
GROUP BY Student
Having COUNT(ClubName) > 1

Student   Number of Clubs
=========================
Bob           2
Frank         2
Tom           3
```

What I would like to do is list the Club Names each student belongs to in columns, like this ...

```
Student      Club1     Club2    Club3
=====================================
Bob          Chess     Tennis
Frank        Soccer    Math
Tom          Chess     Math     Drama
```

Is this possible to do in the same query that determines which students belong to more than one club?

P.S. I gave the example using names rather than IDs as I felt it would be easier to explain/read. In my real table I use Student IDs and Club IDs.

Comment: Look for *dynamic pivot*. You can find many similar questions here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you some programming language, it is easy to list the result. First, you can create a HashMap, key the studentName/studentId, value is a list. You can put the clubName/clubId into the list. After you get the map, you can traverse the map and print out the result you want. Here is the pseudo code

1. new a hashMap>//key is the student Id, values is the club list
2. select studentid,clubId from the table and store it into resultset
3. traverse the resultset, put the proper value into the hashmap
4. traverse the hashmap and print out the vales
   for key:hashmap.keysets
   print key:hashmap.get(Key)

Comment: could do as you suggest and manipulate to result set in code but ideally I would like to see if I could do this via a SQL script.